# How to change specific field in custom type arrays' element?

Tags: arrays, types, julia

Here is the deal. I made a custom type in Julia lang:

```
type points
  x::Float64
  y::Float64
  z::Float64
end
```

And also made an array of this type:

```
S = Array(ponits,1,Int(N))
```

So now I want to change field x of i's (e.g. i=3) array element to, for example, 4.28. But when I do this:

```
S[3].x = 4.28
```

it changes ALL array S. Thus I have array S with all elements having x-filed equals 4.28. I read Julia's documentations and did not find anything about this. How does it work in Julia?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Oh, since I already made this thread. How to make a zero-element of custom type? For exaplme, zero of points type would be something like (0,0,0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an array of references to a same object, and try to mutate one of them you will get that result, e.g. if using `fill()` function to fill an array with an object, may leads to the following issue:

```
julia> s=Vector{Points}(3)
3-element Array{Points,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
julia> fill!(s,Points(NaN,NaN,NaN))
3-element Array{Points,1}:
 Points(NaN,NaN,NaN)
 Points(NaN,NaN,NaN)
 Points(NaN,NaN,NaN)
julia> s[1].x=1
1.0

julia> s
3-element Array{Points,1}:
 Points(1.0,NaN,NaN)
 Points(1.0,NaN,NaN)
 Points(1.0,NaN,NaN)
```

To avoid this kind of issue use the array-comprehension to fill it:

`s=[Points(NaN,NaN,NaN) for i=1:3]`

But what I see from your sample code is that:

The `Points` datatype do not have a custom `constructor` and besides that, `s` array have not been initialized.

```
julia> s = Array(Points,1,4)
1x4 Array{points,2}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef  #undef
```

so if you try to mutate on element you will get an error:

```
julia> s[1].x
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
 in getindex at array.jl:282
```

one solution with minimal changes is to use `Points` default constructor like this:

```
s[1]=Points(NaN,NaN,NaN)
```

After that you will be able to mutate element of `s` , `s[1].x=4.28`

**Secondly** to have `zero` of `Points` type, you should add `zero(::Points)` method:

```
julia> import Base.zero

julia> zero(::Points)=Points(0,0,0)
zero (generic function with 14 methods)

julia> zero(Points(1,2,3))
Points(0.0,0.0,0.0)
```

**Tip**: Using an 1XN array to handle an `Array` of N elements is not the best choice, [Refer](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns), use `Vector{Type}(N)` instead.